# Bean property 'favLang' is not readable or has an invalid getter method: Does the return type of the getter match the parameter type of the setter?

Tags: spring, forms, spring-mvc, jsp, spring-form

I have created a spring mvc project with simple form and model. On running the project it gives below error:
Invalid property 'favLang' of bean class [com.springdemo.mvc.Student]: Bean property 'favLang' is not readable or has an invalid getter method: Does the return type of the getter match the parameter type of the setter?

**Student.java**

```
package com.springdemo.mvc;

import java.util.LinkedHashMap;

public class Student {

    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String countryName;
    private LinkedHashMap<String, String> countryOptions;
    private String favLang;

    public Student() {

        countryOptions = new LinkedHashMap<>(); 
        countryOptions.put("BR", "Brazil");
        countryOptions.put("IN", "India");
        countryOptions.put("FR", "France");
        countryOptions.put("GE", "Germany");

    }

    public LinkedHashMap<String, String> getCountryOptions() {
        return countryOptions;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getCountryName() {
        return countryName;
    }

    public void setCountryName(String countryName) {
        this.countryName = countryName;
    }

    public String getFavLang() {
        return favLang;
    }

    public void setFavLang(String favLang) {
        this.favLang = favLang;
    }


}
```

**Student-Controller**

```
package com.springdemo.mvc;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/student")
public class StudentController {

    @RequestMapping("/showForm")
    public String showForm(Model theModel) {

        //create a new student object
        Student theStudent=new Student();

        //add student object as model attribute
        theModel.addAttribute("student", new Student());

        return "student-form";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/processForm")
    public String processForm(@ModelAttribute("student") Student theStudent) {

        System.out.println("theStudent: "+theStudent.getFirstName());
        return "student-confirmation";
    }

}
```

**student-form.jsp:**

```
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>

<html>
<head>
<title>Student Registration</title>
</head>
<body>

<form:form action="processForm" modelAttribute="student">
    First Name : <form:input path="firstName"/>
    <br><br>
    Last Name: <form:input path="lastName"/>
    <br><br>
<!--    Country :  -->
<%--    <form:select path="countryName"> --%>
<%--     <form:options items="${student.countryOptions}"/> --%>
<%--    </form:select> --%>
    <br><br>

    Fav Language: 
    Java <form:radiobutton path="favLang" value="Java"/>
    C++ <form:radiobutton path="favLang" value="C++"/>
    C# <form:radiobutton path="favLang" value="C#"/>
    PHP <form:radiobutton path="favLang" value="PHP"/>

    <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>


</form:form>
</body>

</html>
```

**student-confirmation.jsp**

```
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Student Confirmation Page</title>
</head>
<body>
<p>The student is confirmed: ${student.firstName} ${student.lastName} </p>
<%-- <p>Country: ${student.countryName}</p> --%>
<p>Fav Language: ${student.favLang}</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Full stack trace of error:

```
org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.RequestContextAwareTag doStartTag
SEVERE: Invalid property 'favLang' of bean class [com.springdemo.mvc.Student]: Bean property 'favLang' is not readable or has an invalid getter method: Does the return type of the getter match the parameter type of the setter?
org.springframework.beans.NotReadablePropertyException: Invalid property 'favLang' of bean class [com.springdemo.mvc.Student]: Bean property 'favLang' is not readable or has an invalid getter method: Does the return type of the getter match the parameter type of the setter?
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.getPropertyValue(AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.java:622)
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.getPropertyValue(AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.java:612)
    at org.springframework.validation.AbstractPropertyBindingResult.getActualFieldValue(AbstractPropertyBindingResult.java:104)
    at org.springframework.validation.AbstractBindingResult.getFieldValue(AbstractBindingResult.java:228)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.support.BindStatus.<init>(BindStatus.java:129)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getBindStatus(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:177)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getPropertyPath(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:198)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getName(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:163)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.autogenerateId(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:148)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractCheckedElementTag.autogenerateId(AbstractCheckedElementTag.java:86)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.resolveId(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:138)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractSingleCheckedElementTag.writeTagContent(AbstractSingleCheckedElementTag.java:89)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractFormTag.doStartTagInternal(AbstractFormTag.java:86)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.RequestContextAwareTag.doStartTag(RequestContextAwareTag.java:83)
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.view.student_002dform_jsp._jspx_meth_form_005fradiobutton_005f0(student_002dform_jsp.java:329)
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.view.student_002dform_jsp._jspx_meth_form_005fform_005f0(student_002dform_jsp.java:205)
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.view.student_002dform_jsp._jspService(student_002dform_jsp.java:140)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:476)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:385)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:329)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:712)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:459)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:384)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:312)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:170)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:316)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1371)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1117)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1056)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:942)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1005)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:897)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:490)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:678)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:853)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1587)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Sep 26, 2019 3:18:47 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [jsp] threw exception
org.springframework.beans.NotReadablePropertyException: Invalid property 'favLang' of bean class [com.springdemo.mvc.Student]: Bean property 'favLang' is not readable or has an invalid getter method: Does the return type of the getter match the parameter type of the setter?
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.getPropertyValue(AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.java:622)
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.getPropertyValue(AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.java:612)
    at org.springframework.validation.AbstractPropertyBindingResult.getActualFieldValue(AbstractPropertyBindingResult.java:104)
    at org.springframework.validation.AbstractBindingResult.getFieldValue(AbstractBindingResult.java:228)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.support.BindStatus.<init>(BindStatus.java:129)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getBindStatus(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:177)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getPropertyPath(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:198)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getName(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:163)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.autogenerateId(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:148)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractCheckedElementTag.autogenerateId(AbstractCheckedElementTag.java:86)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.resolveId(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:138)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractSingleCheckedElementTag.writeTagContent(AbstractSingleCheckedElementTag.java:89)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractFormTag.doStartTagInternal(AbstractFormTag.java:86)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.RequestContextAwareTag.doStartTag(RequestContextAwareTag.java:83)
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.view.student_002dform_jsp._jspx_meth_form_005fradiobutton_005f0(student_002dform_jsp.java:329)
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.view.student_002dform_jsp._jspx_meth_form_005fform_005f0(student_002dform_jsp.java:205)
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.view.student_002dform_jsp._jspService(student_002dform_jsp.java:140)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:476)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:385)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:329)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:712)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:459)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:384)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:312)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:170)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:316)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1371)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1117)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1056)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:942)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1005)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:897)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:490)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:678)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:853)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1587)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Sep 26, 2019 3:18:47 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcher] in context with path [/spring-mvc-demo] threw exception [An exception occurred processing [/WEB-INF/view/student-form.jsp] at line [21]

18:     <br><br>
19:     
20:     Fav Language: 
21:     Java <form:radiobutton path="favLang" value="Java"/>
22:     C++ <form:radiobutton path="favLang" value="C++"/>
23:     C# <form:radiobutton path="favLang" value="C#"/>
24:     PHP <form:radiobutton path="favLang" value="PHP"/>


Stacktrace:] with root cause
org.springframework.beans.NotReadablePropertyException: Invalid property 'favLang' of bean class [com.springdemo.mvc.Student]: Bean property 'favLang' is not readable or has an invalid getter method: Does the return type of the getter match the parameter type of the setter?
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.getPropertyValue(AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.java:622)
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.getPropertyValue(AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.java:612)
    at org.springframework.validation.AbstractPropertyBindingResult.getActualFieldValue(AbstractPropertyBindingResult.java:104)
    at org.springframework.validation.AbstractBindingResult.getFieldValue(AbstractBindingResult.java:228)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.support.BindStatus.<init>(BindStatus.java:129)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getBindStatus(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:177)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getPropertyPath(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:198)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getName(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:163)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.autogenerateId(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:148)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractCheckedElementTag.autogenerateId(AbstractCheckedElementTag.java:86)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.resolveId(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:138)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractSingleCheckedElementTag.writeTagContent(AbstractSingleCheckedElementTag.java:89)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractFormTag.doStartTagInternal(AbstractFormTag.java:86)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.RequestContextAwareTag.doStartTag(RequestContextAwareTag.java:83)
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.view.student_002dform_jsp._jspx_meth_form_005fradiobutton_005f0(student_002dform_jsp.java:329)
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.view.student_002dform_jsp._jspx_meth_form_005fform_005f0(student_002dform_jsp.java:205)
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.view.student_002dform_jsp._jspService(student_002dform_jsp.java:140)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:476)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:385)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:329)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:712)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:459)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:384)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:312)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:170)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:316)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1371)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1117)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1056)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:942)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1005)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:897)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:490)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:678)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:853)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1587)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Can someone pls let me know what might be the issue here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add object in to modelAndView return that from StudentController.
Check following changes in code and run project.

**Student.java**

```
  public class Student {

  private String firstName;
  private String lastName;
  private String countryName;
  private LinkedHashMap<String, String> countryOptions;
  private String favLang;

  public Student() {

  countryoptions = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();
  countryoptions.put("BR", "Brazil");
  countryoptions.put("IN", "India");
  countryoptions.put("FR", "France");
  countryoptions.put("GE", "Germany");

  }

  public LinkedHashMap<String, String> getCountryOptions() {
      return countryoptions;
  }
  public String getFirstname() {
      return firstname;
  }
  public void setFirstname(String firstname) {
      this.firstname = firstname;
  }
  public String getLastname() {
      return lastname;
  }
  public void setLastname(String lastname) {
      this.lastname = lastname;
  }
  public String getCountryname() {
      return countryname;
  }
  public void setCountryname(String countryname) {
      this.countryname = countryname;
  }
  public LinkedHashMap<String, String> getCountryoptions() {
      return countryoptions;
  }
  public void setCountryoptions(LinkedHashMap<String, String> countryoptions) {
      this.countryoptions = countryoptions;
  }
  public String getFavlang() {
      return favlang;
  }
  public void setFavlang(String favlang) {
      this.favlang = favlang;
  }
}
```

**Student-Controller.java**

```
@Controller
public class StudentController {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/showForm", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView showRegister(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse 
    response) {
        ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("student-form");
        mav.addObject("student", new Student());
        return mav;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/processForm", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView addUser(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse 
    response,@ModelAttribute("student") Student student) {

        ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("student-confirmation");
        mav.addObject("firstname", student.getFirstname());
        mav.addObject("favName", student.getFavlang());
        return mav;
   }
}
```

**student-form.jsp:**

```
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>

<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Registration</title>
</head>
<body>
<form:form id="regForm" modelAttribute="user" action="processForm"
    method="post">

<table align="center">
        <tr>
            <td><form:label path="firstname">Username</form:label></td>
            <td><form:input path="firstname" name="username" id="username" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><form:label path="lastname">Password</form:label></td>
            <td><form:password path="lastname" name="password"
                    id="password" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                 Fav Language:
    Java <form:radiobutton path="favlang" value="Java"/>
   C++ <form:radiobutton path="favlang" value="C++"/>
   C# <form:radiobutton path="favlang" value="C#"/>
   PHP <form:radiobutton path="favlang" value="PHP"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>

<input type="submit" value="Submit"/>

</form:form>
```

**student-confirmation.jsp**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
 <html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Welcome</title>
</head>
<body>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Welcome ${firstname}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><p>Fav Language: ${favName}</p></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Please mark as answer if this solution work for you.